# PIC32 How do I find group number for peripheral

Tags: pic

From my last question I made a mistake on thinking SCK was under PPS control.  I see that now but I still don't understand how to figure out group number for a function with PPS by reading the datasheet.

Let's say I want to bring out MOSI, or I think that's SDO2 in PIC land.   On my board it's connected to Pin 22, SDO2_RPB11.  And I'm still using a PIC32MX210F016B.

Using their macro:  `PPSOutput(2, RPA1, SDO1);`

I have to specify a group as the first input, then pin, then function.  For some reason I'm not seeing where the datasheet specifies what group to use.

I'm guessing by reading the pps.h header that it's something like this:

```
PPSOutput(2, RPB11, SDO2);
```

I'm not sure though that does compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion that 'Group Number' parameter is pretty poorly documented.

How I've figured it out is to look at the PPS Pin Selection table for either inputs or outputs (tables 11-1 & 11-2 in your datasheet).
Then, for inputs find the input function or for outputs find the pin you're interested in from the left-most column and then look over to the right-most column of the table.
You'll see they're 'grouped' - so for example:
 - INT4, T2CK, IC4, SS1, REFCLKI are all in Group 1
 - INT3, T3CK, IC3, U1CTS, U2RX, SDI1 are in Group 2
 - etc ...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the datasheet of the device in the table 11-1 (page 146) you will notice the grouping in the rightmost column. If you look at the `pps.h` file as well, you will see the definitions:

```
/* Output Pin Group 1 */
#define _PPS_OUTPUT_BASE_ADDRESS RPA0R // Happens to be the first one
#define OUT_PIN_PPS1_RPA0        RPA0Rbits.RPA0R
#define OUT_PIN_PPS1_RPB3        RPB3Rbits.RPB3R
#define OUT_PIN_PPS1_RPB4        RPB4Rbits.RPB4R

.........
```

Which are corresponding to this grouping. So you have actually two sources for this information.